# Ubuntu 20.04 Stuck on Black Screen Before Login

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, recovery-mode

My computer is stuck on black screen with cursor before **Login** after booting into Ubuntu 20.04, nothing is working, even cursor is not moving, its freeze, i also tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> its not opening the terminal. When i restart the system and in grub menu select the `Advance options for Ubuntu` and select the recovery mode, the recovery mode is not working too, its stuck. Only **old** recovery mode is working. How to Fix this problem?

**Update**

During OS installation i think i have selected the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, codecs, etc.(not sure)

**Hardware Specs:**

Intel Core i7
,Gtx 1060
,16 Ram
,1TB nvme ssd

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press "e" to edit the entry you're trying to boot and remove "splash" or even "quiet splash". Does it boot now or if i doesn't what are the error messages?

Comment: @ChanganAuto i didn't get your point. i am stuck on black screen with a cursor, nothing is working

Comment: Yes, but that is *after* the Grub menu selection, isn't it? If not I don't see the point of posting a photo of the Grub menu. Is at that Grub menu that you can try what I suggested.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes after selection... i post grub bocz i wanted to mention that old version is working, but default is not working.. it was working yesterday and before.

Comment: So, *before* pressing enter on the default, edit it as explained above. This is for testing purposes only. mIf it works then you can make it permanent.

Comment: @ChanganAuto no, its not working.. no error message showing too.

Comment: Now we need so more details, hardware specifications and particularly the graphics.

Comment: @ChanganAuto gtx 1060, core i7 7700, 16 ram, 1tb nvme ssd

Comment: So, first of all, please edit the question and add that information so it doesn't become  lost in comments. Now, (1) make sure Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI. (2) Have you installed Nvidia drivers or during the OS installation have you selected the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, codecs, etc. Also add all relevant information to the question itself.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i think i selected the option install 3rd party.. I don't remember

Comment: You can search 'black screen of death' and should get some results.

Comment: When the grub menu comes up, press 'e'. The grub config will open in edit mode. Add "nomodeset" to the values of "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT", space separated. Save and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

On grub menu i select `Advance options for Ubuntu` then i select `Ubuntu, linux 5.8.0-53-generic` instead of `Ubuntu, linux 5.8.0-55-generic`(it was the default one which was not working), after booting and login into the system i went into software updater, software updater was giving me the option of Partial Upgrade or Continue, i selected the Partial Upgrade, it removed and installed some packages now the default `Ubuntu, linux 5.8.0-55-generic` is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Its stuck on black screen after boot, i am not able to login and open anything.

Comment: edit grub option as suggested in other comments and upgrade graphics drivers